# Есть в базе многомерный массив категорий

Tags: php, mysql

В базе есть многомерный массив категорий, как получить последнего потомка из этого массива на php?

**Пример**

```
Категория 1
...категория 1.1
......категория 1.1.1
Категория 2
...категория 2.1
......категория 2.1.1
```

Нужно получить 1.х.х.... 2.х.х.х....

```
вид даблиц
id     name     parent_id
1  Категория 1     0
2  Категория 2     1
.. .......................
```

Comment: Какая у тебя структура таблицы и данных? Я не могу представить в каком вид у тебя хранятся данные в таблице.

Comment: Вот посмотри решения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076539/using-php-to-display-a-tree-structure-pulled-from-a-database

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result